# Reason for this ratsnest in Kicad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout, kicad

When (re)designing my board, I came across a ratsnest that I cannot understand its reason, nor do I know how to connect something in order to remove it.

This is the ratsnest that I am talking about (the blue line, 45 degrees).

[image]

Comment: Please zoom out. Are they connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two copper areas appear to be disconnected even if they should be connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One GND zone was left without connection.